# pyspark dataframe "condition should be string or Column"

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, pyspark

i am unable to use a filter on a data frame. i keep getting error "TypeError("condition should be string or Column")"

I have tried changing the filter to use col object. Still, it does not work.

```
path = 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/TravelData.txt'
data = spark.read.text(path)
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType , StringType, DoubleType
schema = StructType([
  StructField("fromLocation", StringType(), True),
  StructField("toLocation", StringType(), True),
  StructField("productType", IntegerType(), True)
])
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(path, header=False, schema=schema)
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
answerthree = df.select("toLocation").groupBy("toLocation").count().sort("count", ascending=False).take(10)  # works fine
display(answerthree)
```

I add a filter to variable "answerthree" as follows:

```
answerthree = df.select("toLocation").groupBy("toLocation").count().filter(col("productType")==1).sort("count", ascending=False).take(10)
```

It is throwing error as follows:
""cannot resolve '`productType`' given input columns""condition should be string or Column"

In jist, i am trying to solve problem 3 given in below link using pyspark instead of scal. Dataset is also provided in below url.
https://acadgild.com/blog/spark-use-case-travel-data-analysis?fbclid=IwAR0fgLr-8aHVBsSO_yWNzeyh7CoiGraFEGddahDmDixic6wmumFwUlLgQ2c

I should be able to get the desired result only for productType value 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't have a variable referencing the data frame, the easiest is to use a string condition:

```
answerthree = df.select("toLocation").groupBy("toLocation").count()\
                .filter("productType = 1")\
                .sort(...
```

Alternatively, you can use a data frame variable and use a column-based filter:

```
count_df = df.select("toLocation").groupBy("toLocation").count()
answerthree = count_df.filter(count_df['productType'] == 1)\
                      .sort("count", ascending=False).take(10)
```

Comment: The second alternative works fine but the first one still gives an error.
answerthree = df.select("toLocation").groupBy("toLocation").count().filter("productType = 1").sort("count", ascending=False).take(10)

error:
"cannot resolve '`productType`' given input columns: [toLocation, count]; line 1 pos 0;